# Appending li inside ul using function shows undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append

I used the below to append my `li` to `ul` using function to generate `li`s.

When print in console it shows `li` but when appending it shows undefined.

Please help me.

```js
divClassName = ".extra-attri-div";
htmlDiv = "";
$.each(result, function(index, value) {
  $.each(value, function(index, values) {
    if (values != "") {
      if (jQuery.inArray(index.toUpperCase(), segList) !== -1) {
        htmlDiv += '<div class="col appendeddiv"><div class="label-value"><label class="extraattrlebl">' + index + '</label><div class="value"><ul id=li-' + index + '>' + generateListSegAttr(values, index) + '</ul></div></div></div>';
      }
    }
  });
});
$(divClassName).append(htmlDiv);


function generateListSegAttr(values, id) {
  console.log(values + "---------------" + id);
  var htmlUlLi = "";
  if (values != "") {

    var arrayAttr = values.split(',');
    $.each(arrayAttr, function(index, value) {
      console.log(index + "*******" + value);
      htmlUlLi += "<li>" + value + "</li>";
    });
    console.log("#li-" + id);
    $("#li-" + id).append(htmlUlLi);
    console.log("Html" + htmlUlLi);

  } else {
    $("#" + id).append(htmlUlLi);
  }
}
```

Comment: check if you don't go in else

Comment: its not coming to else part.I got my li too but it shows undefined when append....frustrated more than an hour

Comment: Your `generateListSegAttr` doesn't `return` anything so there's nothing for the `"+generateListSegAttr(..)+"` to concat

Comment: You have to return in generateListSegAttr function and not append. return htmlUlLi. And it will output the li html in string abouve.

Comment: Inside generateListSegAttr, you use `$("#li-" + id).append` - but `#li-" + id` hasn't yet been added to the DOM (as it's still being built in a string) so there's nothing to append to, so does nothing - change `$("#li-" + id).append(htmlUlLi);` to `return htmlUlLi;` and you're done.